# How to view the origin of HTTP requests?

Tags: newrelic

One of my company's internal HTTP endpoints are receiving a large number requests but we don't know where they are coming from. How can I trace the origin of these requests?

**Update:**
I forgot to mention that I want to view the origin of the requests using NewRelic. I also don't have the luxury of installing debugging tools like Fiddler in my production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic [does not track](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/capture-incoming-ip-address-or-system-name-of-incoming-requests/34534) identifiers like source IP address out-of-the-box. You must implement custom instrumentation within your app to track those identifiers.

For example, you can [add a custom attribute](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/agent-data/collect-custom-attributes) to the `Transaction` or `PageView` event type that will track the source IP address, or you can [record a custom event](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-data-sources/custom-events/insert-custom-events-insights-api) in Insights.

If you add a custom attribute, then you should be able to use New Relic Insights with a query like:

```
SELECT `source.ip.address` FROM Transaction
```

If you add a custom event, then you should be able to use New Relic Insights with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM YourCustomEventName
```

New Relic's [custom instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/agent-data/custom-instrumentation) will enable you to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a tool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).